# VisualState Storyboard.TargetName in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml

I'm new to working with VisualStates and wondered how to set a Storyboard.TargetName to the control that is being styled ?

I hope the following snippet will make my question a little clearer.

```
<Style x:Key="AppBarBtnStyle" TargetType="AppBarButton">

    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="AppBarButton">
<Grid x:Name="Root"
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Flash">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="WHAT GOES HERE TO TARGET THE BORDERBRUSH SET PREVIOUSLY ABOVE" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"  Duration="0:0:1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to set a Storyboard.TargetName to the control that is being styled ?

It seems like you want to animate the `<Setter>` which property is `BorderBrush`. Actually when a Style is used to define a control template, the TargetType of the Style element and the TargetType of the ControlTemplate element for its Control.Template setter should always use the same value.Details please reference Styles and templates section of [Setter class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.setter).

For example, the `BorderBrush` property you can find it in `Grid` control which named `Root` inside the [AppBarButton styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299105.aspx).

```
<Grid
    x:Name="Root"
    MinWidth="{TemplateBinding MinWidth}"
    MaxWidth="{TemplateBinding MaxWidth}"
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
```

So that you can met your requierements by setting the `Storyboard.TargetName` to `Root` element for the color animation here.

```
<VisualState x:Name="Normal">
    <Storyboard>
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames
            Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
            Duration="0:0:5">
            <LinearColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="Blue" />
            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:2.5" Value="Yellow" />
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="OverflowTextLabel" />
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```